Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS Bluetooth unable to detect Sony WH-CH520 headphone
I am trying to connect Sony WH-CH520 headphone to my Ubuntu laptop. But I can't see the headphone name in the list of available devices. The headphone is also on, I tried pressing the power button and the light blinks. Any solutions to fix it?
Here are the results from lsusb; sudo dmesg |egrep -i 'blue|firm'
debashis@debashis:~$ lsusb; sudo dmesg |egrep -i 'blue|firm'
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 27c6:55a4 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Goodix FingerPrint Device
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 30c9:003a Luxvisions Innotech Limited Integrated Camera
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c542 Logitech, Inc. Wireless Receiver
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[sudo] password for debashis: 
[    0.154148] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.430351] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x5f3001)
[    2.170923] elan_i2c 0-0015: unexpected iap version 0x00 (ic type: 0x17), firmware update will not work
[    2.170937] elan_i2c 0-0015: Elan Touchpad: Module ID: 0x0017, Firmware: 0x004f, Sample: 0x0000, IAP: 0x0000
[    2.242326] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 77.2df8986f.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-77.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.723685] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/tgl_dmc_ver2_12.bin (v2.12)
[    2.778135] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.778153] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    2.778154] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.778157] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.778159] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.778163] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.873484] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.4 build 0 week 30 2018
[    2.874519] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 2
[    2.874527] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[    2.874533] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[    2.874537] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[    2.874542] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[    2.874543] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    2.876396] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-19-0-4.sfi
[    2.876411] Bluetooth: hci0: Boot Address: 0x24800
[    2.876412] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware Version: 206-22.23
[    3.205433] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.205436] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.205440] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    3.262058] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:0:0-b678a
[    3.262063] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:20:0 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
[    3.360133] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:0:0-b678a
[    3.360139] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:20:0 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
[    4.543102] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[    4.543466] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1627995 usecs
[    4.543499] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[    4.558473] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 14639 usecs
[    4.558481] Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
[    4.558730] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-19-0-4.ddc
[    4.560475] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[    4.564785] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.4 build 206 week 22 2023
[    4.566488] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI LE Coded PHY feature bit is set, but its usage is not supported.
[    4.642518] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[   10.504773] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   10.504781] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   10.504786] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11


Please edit the question to include results from terminal for lsusb; sudo dmesg |egrep -i 'blue|firm'

Hi @Jeremy31  Thanks, added the results. please check.

Try bluetoothctl followed by power on scan on quit and see if they are found, are the headphones in pairing mode?

Tried, no success..its not visible. Yes, headphones are in pairing mode. It also works fine, it connects to my android mobile.

It's solved now. Make sure the headphones are in pairing mode. Hold a long tap then it will have quick blinks:)
Sorry for the noise.

Good, I have the same bluetooth on a mini PC running Mint and it worked fine

Switch off Sony WH-CH520 headphone:
Press and hold Power button for 5 seconds

Clear device list (I didn't know how else to set the device into pairing mode)
Press and hold the Power button and the Volume Down button simultaneously for about 10 seconds.

Open a terminal and type
bluetoothctl

this changes the shell prompt to [bluetooth]. Now enter
power on
scan on

Then wait for the right MAC address to appear. Now (still in the same program) enter
connect <MAC_ADDRESS>

Tested on Ubuntu 24.04. Thanks to Jeremy31!
